# MongoDB - FieldPath '%Y-%m-%d' doesn't start with $

Tags: mongodb, grouping, aggregation-framework

> assert: command failed: {
>           "ok" : 0,
>           "errmsg" : "FieldPath '%Y-%m-%d' doesn't start with $",
>           "code" : 16873
>   } : aggregate failed

I have a query below, which is giving me an error which I am not getting rid of.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            'insertedAt': {
                $gte: ISODate("2017-02-23T01:00:01Z")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group : {
            _id : {
                isDummy: '$isDummy',
                $dateToString: {
                    format: '%Y-%m-%d',
                    date: '$insertedAt'
                }
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: I can't upvote, help me to get 15 reputations!

Comment: You don't have to upvote. You can continue [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer by  for now and you will gain some reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) is an expression which is used to convert date into required format. use below one and you are ready to go.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            'insertedAt': {
                $gte: ISODate("2017-02-23T01:00:01Z")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group : {
            _id : {
                isDummy: '$isDummy',
                insertedAt: {
                   $dateToString: {
                    format: '%Y-%m-%d',
                    date: '$insertedAt'
                   }
                }
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

[$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) is an aggregation operator and converts a date type to string.

Change to

```
_id: {
    isDummy: '$isDummy',
    insertedAt: {
        $dateToString: {
            format: '%Y-%m-%d',
            date: '$insertedAt'
        }
    }
}
```